# css text not aligning to the left

Tags: css, reactjs, grid

I have a div (which is present in a grid) where I'm displaying some text. I'd like the text to be aligned to the left, so I set text-align to left. But, this doesn't work. The text is aligned to the centre by default, and no matter what I do, I can't get it to align to the left.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

The code:

```
function BookPage(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <TabBar />
            <div className="grid-container">
                <div className="book-description">
                    <img src={userImage} alt="" />
                    <div className="content">
                        <h2>Game of Thrones</h2>
                        <p>George R.R. Martin</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="book-detail">heh</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

css:

```
.grid-container {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 500px;
}

.book-description {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  text-align: start;
}

.book-detail {
  grid-column: 3 / 3;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text-align property needs to be set to the exact tags that the content is displayed in. You can do this in one of 2 ways in your current css:

```
.content h2, .content p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

or you can create a new class and give that class directly to the h2 and p tags, such as:

```
.alignLeft {
    text-align: left;
}
```